# PM2 Error - Error: Error: spawn wmic ENONET

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, pm2, wmic

I'm currently working on a Discord Bot using javascript. I recently updated my NodeJS version to the LTS (12.16.2), my npm to 5.7.1 and my pm2 to 4.4.0.

I can start my process perfectly fine with "pm2 start index.js", however as the process goes along it will start to shoot this weird error about WMIC (this error also happens when trying to restart).

```
PM2      | Error caught while calling pidusage
PM2      | Error: Error: spawn wmic ENOENT
PM2      |     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\pidusage\lib\bin.js:33:10)
PM2      |     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
PM2      |     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
PM2      |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
PM2      |     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
PM2      |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I have updated my Environment Variables to include "C:\Windows\System32\wbem" and I can confirm that folder exists and has WMIC.exe in it. I have also tried doing "pm2 start index.js --update-env". Some help with this error would be wonderful.

Comment: ENOENT error happening when you don't have access to file.check the existence or access rights of the file with fs.access(dir, options, callback)

Comment: try to run pm2 with elevated permission and check

Comment: @SandeepPatel I'm not sure how to do that on Windows 10. That's where I code my bot. I know how to on Linux. If you know how let me know thanks.

Comment: type cmd in search  and right-click on cmd you will see  option run as administrator

Comment: @SandeepPatel Oh, I've already done that. I always run cmd as admin